# Can not run bash script in pm2 on docker alpine image

Tags: bash, docker, pm2, alpine-linux

I have created an image from the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk add nodejs-current
RUN apk add nodejs-npm
RUN npm install pm2 -g
COPY process.yaml .
CMD pm2 start process.yaml --no-daemon --log-date-format 'DD-MM 
HH:mm:ss.SSS'
```

`process.yaml` looks like this:

```
- script: ./run-services.sh
  watch : false
```

But `run-services.sh` does not run in my docker. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in alpine the `bash` is not installed by default. `pm2` runs bash scripts files by `bash` command. so there is two way to solve the problem:

1. Changing default `pm2` interpreter from `bash` to `/bin/sh`

   ```
   - script: ./run-services.sh
     interpreter: /bin/sh
     watch : false
   ```
2. Installing `bash` in alpine. So the Dockerfile changes as following:

   ```
   FROM alpine
   RUN apk update && apk add bash
   WORKDIR /usr/src/app
   RUN apk add nodejs-current
   RUN apk add nodejs-npm
   RUN npm install pm2 -g
   COPY process.yaml .
   CMD pm2 start process.yaml --no-daemon --log-date-format 'DD-MM 
   HH:mm:ss.SSS'
   ```